# React update checkbox from object value

Tags: html, reactjs, checkbox

I'm trying to control a checkbox by using the value property that is coming from `tableData`. And by default the value is `true`.

```
let newData = newRes.data.map((e) => {
        return {
          ...e,
          installmentChecked: true,
          lateFeeChecked: true,
          depositChecked: true,
          collectionChecked: true,
        };
      });
     setTableData(newData);
```

After I mapped the data, I return the input like this.

```
const { data, index } = props;
return(
...
<input
  type="checkbox"
  value={latefee}
  checked={data?.lateFeeChecked}
  onChange={() => onChangeCheckbox('lateFeeChecked', index,data?.lateFeeChecked)}
/>
...
```

And this how I handle the value of the object.

```
const onChangeCheckbox = (key, index,status) => {
    tableData[index][key] = !tableData[index][key];
    console.log(tableData[index][key], 'props key');
    console.log(status, 'status');
  };
```

The problem that I'm getting is, the checkbox won't change at all. When I click, the console says.

```
false 'props key'
true 'status'
```

Is there any problem with my code? Or maybe anyone could gimme a better way to handle a checkbox in React?
Appreciate any kind of responses, thanks before.

Comment: You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that people can understand your problem clearly. mind if you could make a sandbox where you can show full code. If you like you can use https://codesandbox.io/ . This will make easier to understand what exactly is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to let react know to rerender your component.
You need to use `useState` hook to achieve that.

It looks like you have `setTableData` it is not clear if that's connected to `useState` by the code you shared.

If it is,
you need to do this:

```
const onChangeCheckbox = (key, index,status) => {
    setTableData({
      ...tableData, 
      [index][key]: !tableData[index][key],
    });
  };
```

Comment: thanks I got the idea, it's because of the component didn't re-rendering every time I clicks the button

Answer (score 0):

```
const { data, index } = props;
return(
...
<input
  type="checkbox"
  value={latefee ? ‘true’:’’}
  checked={data?.lateFeeChecked ? ‘checked’ : ‘’}
  onChange={() => onChangeCheckbox('lateFeeChecked', index,data?.lateFeeChecked)}
/>
```

You may try this, as sometimes html doesn’t understand boolean value provided in React, and in those cases we need to provide boolean value in string.